# How can I transform a List<string> into XML using Linq?

Tags: c#-3.0, linq-to-xml

The inverse question of [How can I transform XML into a List or String[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956749/how-can-i-transform-xml-into-a-liststring-or-string).

I have a `List<string>` of users and want to convert them to the following xml :

```
<Users>
    <User>Domain\Alice</User>
    <User>Domain\Bob</User>
    <User>Domain\Charly</User>
</Users>
```

I am currently wrapping this list in a class and use `XmlSerializer` to solve this but I find this quite heavy ...

So is there a more straightforward solution using Linq to Xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XElement xml = new XElement("Users",
                    (from str in aList select new XElement("User", str)).ToArray());
```

This might do it. Not sure if the .ToArray is necessary.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks a lot. It works fine without the .ToArray()

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<User> list = new List<User>();
        list.Add(new User { Name = "Domain\\Alice" });
        list.Add(new User { Name = "Domain\\Bob" });
        list.Add(new User { Name = "Domain\\Charly" });

        XElement users = new XElement("Users");
        list.ForEach(user => { users.Add(new XElement("User", user.Name)); });

        Console.WriteLine(users);
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works but you are still wrapping the data to a new class, which I was trying to avoid.