# Load list with linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to load a list from xml. each node has few nodes. I know it's possible to do it in a foreach loop like in the picture below, but i would like to avoid using a loop.

this is what I don't want, but without the loop:
[image]

I saw this examle, but it's only for one node "id". 
[How can I transform XML into a List<string> or String[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956749/how-can-i-transform-xml-into-a-liststring-or-string)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var contacts = from c in xdoc.Descendants("contact")
               select new Contact()
               {
                  GUID = (string)c.Element("Guid"),
                  Name = (string)c.Element("Name"),
                  Email = (string)c.Element("Email"),
                  PhoneNumber = (string)c.Element("PhoneNumber")
               };
```

Where `xdoc` is an instance of `XDocument` class.