# How to create a list<string> from simple xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

this is the xml

```
<Basic>
  <Results>
    <Result>a1</Result>
    <Result>a2</Result>
    <Result>a3</Result>
  </Results>
</Basic>
```

I need to read this xml file and create a list that will contain

```
list[0] = a1   
list[1] = a2   
list[2] = a3
```

what is the simple and fast way to do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956749/how-can-i-transform-xml-into-a-liststring-or-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LinqToXml

```
var list = XDocument.Load(filename)
           .Descendants("Result")
           .Select(x => (string)x)
           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

With an XML reader and a codec to convert the DOM tree to a list.